# Return a value of a model dynamically

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method, which calls the API and returns a model as shown below:

```
public class Book
{
   string Name { get; set; }
   string Author { get; set; }
   string Genre { get; set; }
}
```

This is an example function,

```
public static string GetValue(object reference)
{
    Book book = new Book();
    book.Name = "A";
    book.Author = "B";
    book.Genre = "C";

    return ?? // I have no idea
}
```

If I call `GetValue(Name)` then the method should return `book.Name` value. If I call `GetValue(Genre)` then the method should return `book.Genre`.

How can I do it?

Comment: This seems very strange to me. Why not return the model itself and let the calling method choose which property it needs? if you had different types of properties, you would have to return either `object` or `dynamic` - both comes with a cost.

Comment: What is your real problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is it only to return book.Name and book.Genre

Comment: no, Author too. But based on the input parameter, it should return the value as string.

Comment: Are trying to port code from another language that has this feature and C# does it in a different way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
book.GetType().GetProperty(reference).GetValue(book, null);
```

> Make sure that `reference` is a String with name of the property, eg: "Name", "Genre"

```
public static string GetValue(string propertyName)
{
    Book book = new Book();
    book.Name = "A";
    book.Author = "B";
    book.Genre = "C";

    return book.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(book, null).ToString();
    //Don't foget to handle exception

}
```

Answer (score 3):

While this seems a strange use-case, you generally want to return the book, and then directly access the properties on the book. If you need a property multiple times now, your method will call the API every time you try to access one property with this method.

So the direct approach would probably be something like this:

```
   public static R GetValue<R>(Func<Book, R> selector) {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.Name = "A";
        book.Author = "B";
        book.Genre = "C";

        return selector(book);
    }
```

You can then get the value of this book by using a lambda function to indicate what you want:

```
var name = GetValue(b => b.Name);
```

You could then generalize this, to be ably to return any value when you provide it as an input, by making it an extension method:

```
public static R GetValue<T, R>(this T value, Func<T, R> selector) {
    return selector(value);
}
```

then create a new book, and getting the value like this:

```
var name = book.GetValue(b => b.Name);
```

However, you are now in the place where this is a much more direct way to do this:

```
var name = book.Name;
```

At this point, we're back at my initial suggestion, just get the entire book from wherever you're getting it, and directly access the properties on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in an functional way by passing an `MemberExpression` object into the method the same way like LINQ does it. So you can make this method generic, for example typed to Book and then pass in an expression as a second parameter to choose the property value.

Then you might can use the method like `GetValue(myBook, book => book.Name)` or something like that. Unfortunately I could not show you at the moment, but if there is no other idea I will come back to you today evening when my computer is ready again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can modify your book class as follow:

```
public class Book
{
    private string _name;
    private string _author;
    private string _genre;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public string Author
    {
        get { return _author; }
        set { _author = value; }
    }

    public string Genre
    {
        get { return _genre; }
        set { _genre = value; }
    }

    public string GetValue( Criteria criteria)
    {
        switch (criteria)
        {
            case Criteria.Author:
                return _name;                    
            case Criteria.Genre:
                return _genre;                    
            case Criteria.Name:
                return _name;
            default:
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}

public enum Criteria
{
    Name,
    Author,
    Genre
}
```